# GWT CellTable Cells readOnly/disabled/non-editable

Tags: gwt, celltable

I want to make that some cells of the rows can be non-editable.
by now my solution is when i create the columns, if one is readOnly, y make a TextCell, if not, i go with the default Cell wich can be EditTextCell,DatePickerCell,etc.

The problem with this is that i can't make some rows readOnly and others not. Or they are ALL the fields readOnly or they are not.

How can i do to make this for example

TABLE:
Data1       |     Data2         | Data3
--------------------------------------
readOnly  | non-readOnly  | readOnly
readOnly  | readOnly      | non-readOnly

when i mean "readOnly" it can be "enabled" or make it a "TextCell"

```
                    celda = new TextInputCell();
                    Column<ObjetoDato, String> columna = new Column<ObjetoDato, String>(celda) {
                        @Override
                        public String getValue(ObjetoDato object) {
                                if(actual.getValorDefault()!=null && object.getValor(actual.getNombreCampo()).isEmpty()){
                                    object.setValor(actual.getNombreCampo(), actual.getValorDefault());
                                    return actual.getValorDefault();
                                }

                                return object.getValor(actual.getNombreCampo());
                        }
                    };
                    tabla.agregarColumna(columna, actual.getCaption()); 
                    columna.setFieldUpdater(new FieldUpdater<ObjetoDato, String>() {
                              @Override
                            public void update(int index, ObjetoDato object, String value) {
                                object.setValor(actual.getNombreCampo(), value);
                                new Scripter(object,actual.getComportamiento(),true);
                                tabla.actualizar();
                                Sistema.get().getIG().actualizarTotales();
                              }
                    });
```

I tried creating my cutom cell already and replacing the TextImputCell, but the methods never trigger

```
celda = new FabriCel();
```

and

```
public class FabriCel extends TextInputCell {
private String campo;

public FabriCel(String campo){
    this.campo=campo;
}
 @Override
 public void onBrowserEvent(Context context, Element parent, String value, NativeEvent event, ValueUpdater<String> valueUpdater){
     Boolean editable = false;///get it from your model

     if(editable != null && !editable){
         event.preventDefault();
     }else{
         super.onBrowserEvent(context, parent, value, event, valueUpdater);
     }
 }
```

Also this

```
@Override
public void render(com.google.gwt.cell.client.Cell.Context context, String value, SafeHtmlBuilder sb) {
    Boolean editable = false;///get it from your model
    if(editable){
        Log.log();
        sb.appendHtmlConstant("<div contentEditable='false'>"  +value+"</div>");        
    }else{
        Log.log("No entra");
        super.render(context, value, sb);
    }

}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to create one custom cell. In that, you have tell runtime like it should be readonly or no-readonly. just example.

```
        private class CustomCell extends EditTextCell {
            public void render(com.google.gwt.cell.client.Cell.Context context, 
            String value, SafeHtmlBuilder sb) {
            Data data=context.getKey();
            if(data.isReadOnly()){

            sb.appendHtmlConstant("<div contentEditable='false'
             unselectable='false' >"  +value+"</div>");         
                        }else{
                            super.render(context, value, sb);


                        }

                }   
            }
```

In given bean, there is some condition which says readonly or no-readonly.
And create column  like

```
Column<Data, String> nameColumn = new Column<Data, String>(new CustomCell()) {

        @Override
        public String getValue(Data object) {
            return object.getName();

        }
    };
```

Comment: As I given answer you have to create custom cell. and instead of put direct instance of `EditTextCell`, you have to add custom cell.can you put some code?

Comment: If I am not wrong then as I post code your requirement match with it. why are you using `TextInputCell` instead of `EditTextCell`? that I do not understand. when do you want to call `onBrowserEvent` / `render` ? run in debug mode and check with debug point!!

Comment: I finally make it work! helped by https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiCustomCells and you i make it happen.

Answer (score 1):

A way to do this is to override the onBrowserEvent event of your Editable Cells and consume the event if the cell is not editable.

```
            final EditTextCell cell = new EditTextCell(renderer)
            {
                @Override
                public void onBrowserEvent(Context context, Element parent, String value, NativeEvent event, ValueUpdater<String> valueUpdater) 
                {
                    Boolean editable = false;///get it from your model

                    if(editable != null && !editable)
                    {
                        event.preventDefault();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        super.onBrowserEvent(context, parent, value, event, valueUpdater);
                    }
                }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand how to change the cell in runtime. I can't get onBrowserEvent to trigger. I'm nos using DOm elements also...

Comment: If you start typing on the cell the events will go on the onBrowserEvent. Anyway you have mixed the 2 answers.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same need; and tested out various combinations of overriding render, isEditing, resetFocus, and edit on EditTextCell (I didn't try the onBrowserEvent solution).

When I only overrode render (to show an HTML value if non-editable); I got errors resetting focus (as [discussed here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/Google-Web-Toolkit/fE9TLL0_WAs)). This continued even if I overrode resetFocus. When I only override isEditing, the cell would flash to editing when clicked, and then flash back. What worked perfectly was overriding edit. I triggered based on adding a tag to the value passed in by Column.getValue, you can trigger however you like, but it turned out to be as simple as:

```
private static class LockableEditTextCell extends EditTextCell {
    @Override
    protected void edit(Context context, Element parent, java.lang.String value) {
      if (!value.startsWith(LOCKED_CELL_VALUE)) {
        super.edit(context, parent, value);
      }
    }
  }
```